# OpenLayers - is (local) caching possible beyond the LocalStorage?

Tags: openlayers-3

There is a (standard) caching feature for OpenLayers via LocalStorage. The size of LocalStorage is per app max 10Mb.

Is there a (standard or) easy way to cache tiles locally on the mobile so they can be used for offline presentation / navigation? In this way the caching could exceed the 10MB limit.

If so, what are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching map requests are possible in a number of ways. As a first introduction, I refer to [a recommendation for storing data offline](https://medium.com/dev-channel/offline-storage-for-progressive-web-apps-70d52695513c):

- Progressive web apps: for URL addressable resources, use the Cache API (part of Service Worker).
- For all other data, use IndexedDB (with a Promises wrapper).